# angular js Custom directive for pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I want to create a custom directive for pagination which displays total no of filtered records based on text search
Please check my code below:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("testDir",function(){
 return {
    transclude: 'true',
    link:function(scope, element, attr){
        element.append(" Total filtered records:  - <u> "+attr.filtered+"</u> of total records in object: <u>"+attr.unfiltered+"</u>")
        },
        template:"<br/><span ng-transclude> </span> "
 };
});
app.controller("test",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.details = [{value:"record1", other: "record1-value"},
        {value:"record2", other: "record2-value"},
        {value:"record3", other: "record3-value"}];    
}]);
</script>


<div ng-controller="test">
 Please enter text to filter table - 
 <input ng-model= "name">
 <br/>
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "detail in detailFilter=(details | filter:name)">           
        <td>{{detail.value}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 <hr>
 Total filtered Records : {{detailFilter.length}}
 <test-dir filtered="{{detailFilter.length}}" unfiltered="{{details.length}}">Displaying - </test-dir>
 <hr>
```

detailFilter.length display correct length but when i pass it to directive it doesn't pass any object i.e. not even length 0 is displayed for filtered records. I want to pass length of both objects *detailFilter* and *details* to directive.

I've not used directives before and need help with this.

Comment: You need scope: { filtered: "=" } in your directive declaration

Comment: Tried that,it doesn't display anything from directive and is only displaying Total filtered Records : <value>

Comment: Have you achieved your goal here? I achieved this by using an inherited scope. Which is scope = true. But since I'm new to AngularJS I'm not sure what's the best practice of to do this. A few points I noticed are the data are dependent on api calls to render the current page, page numbers, words, etc. for pagination.